# What is difference between "hallen" and "widerhallen"

Tags: meaning, difference

Both verbs of "hallen" and "widerhallen" mean echo. Is there any difference?

Comment: Linguee.de translated _hallen_ as _resound_ and _widerhallen_ as _echo/resound_, but I am not sure if _resound_ means something different as _echo_....

Comment: Did you check a dictionary? If yes, please state why it didn’t help you. If not, please do so and [edit] accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

From intuition, I would say that there might be a tiny difference in usage in that “widerhallen” puts a slight emphasis on the *sound coming back from an object* (“wider-” always means something along the lines of “back”, “against”,…), whereas “hallen” is used more generally.

Another way to put it: I would translate “hallen” as “to echo” and “widerhallen” as “to echo back”.

Answer (score 0):

In general, *hallen* and *widerhallen* can be treated as synonyms. However, *widerhallen* is more precise when you talking about an actual echo, so a sound which is returned by an object. *Hall* - the noun of *hallen* - can also the mean the characteristic of a sound, which sounds "doubled" due to its being echoed from the surrounding objects.

Additionally, *Hall* or *hallen* is significantly more popular than *Widerhall*, as Google Ngram also shows [here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Hall%2C%20Widerhall&year_start=2000&year_end=2015&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CHall%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CWiderhall%3B%2Cc0).

Personally, I would advise using *Hall* and *hallen*.

Comment: Please consider http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/554/how-do-i-format-the-words-in-german-or-another-language-we-are-talking-about

Comment: I disagree. *Hallen* and *Widerhallen* are not synonyms. Example: *Ihr Schrei hallte durch die Straßen* and *Ihr Schrei hallte durch die Straßen wider*. The latter is not possible and would be put as *Ihr Schrei hallte in den Straßen wider*.

Answer (score 0):

*Hallen* can be used in the same contexts as *schallen* (*to sound*). *Widerhallen* has the connotation that the sound is being echoed by some other object.

They can not always be exchanged and thus are not synonyms. An example where they can not be used synonymously would be:

> Der Gesang tausender Fans hallte durch das Stadion.
>   Der Gesang tausender Fans hallte durch das Stadion wider (<= doesn't work)
>   Der Gesang tausender Fans widerhallte durch das Stadion (<= doesn't work either)

Instead of the latter [you could say](http://dwds.de/?view=1&qu=widerhallen)

> Der Gesang tausender Fans hallte im Stadion wider.
>   Der Gesang tausender Fans hallte von den Rängen des Stadions wider.
>   Das Stadion widerhallte vom Gesang tausender Fans.

Also, *hallen* can be used in a way that makes clear that a room or place adds a lot of delay to the sound (which doesn't necessary imply an echo/Widerhall).

> Ein hallender Flur.
>   In der Kirche hallt es ganz schön.